# In sharepoint, how to list all webpartzones of a specific page from object model approach?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using Sharepoint Object Model and after spending some hours with this problem, it looks like SPLimitedWebPartManager doesn't have the "Zones" property (available in SPWebPartManager). I cannot believe the SPLimitedWebPartManager is able to retrieve all the webparts on a specific page (an SPFile), each one with its respective webpartzone assigned, and not able to retrieve all the webparzones of that file!

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Nuno

Answer (score 0):

Alas, SPWebPartZone is a bit of a mysterious topic in the SharePoint object model.  As far as I know, there is no way to identify the zones using the SPLimitedWebPartManager.

Comment: One could retrieve the actual page layout .aspx file and parse it for "<WebPartPages:WebPartZone>" content, but this seems a rather awkward approach. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Even i tried listing webpartzones using SPLimitedWebPartManager  but wasn't successful..But It's possible  using SPWebPartManager ..Will implement and post the code here..